# Verify string has length greater than 0 and is not a space in PHP

Tags: php

How can I verify that a given string is not a space, and is longer than 0 characters using PHP?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming your string is in `$string`:

```
if(strlen(trim($string)) > 0){
   // $string has at least one non-space character
}
```

Note that this will not allow any strings that consist of just spaces, regardless of how many there are.

If you're validating inputs, you might want to think about other degenerate cases, too, like someone entering just an underscore, or other unsuitable input.  If you tell us more about the situation you're trying to deal with we might be able to provide more robust checking.

Comment: Agreed.  Always white-list acceptable characters rather than black-listing unacceptable ones...

Comment: If it's only **one** space you care about, then `strlen($string) > 0 && $string != ' '` could cover it. Trimming unnecessarily could be a bigger operation than necessary for larger strings. Might matter if it's a library function or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use trim and empty.

```
$input = trim($string);
if(empty($input)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

From the PHP docs:

The following things are considered to be [PHP Empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

- "" (an empty string)
- array() (an empty array)

Therefore trimming all whitespace will give you your desired result when combined with empty. However keep in mind that empty will return true for strings of "0".

Comment: `empty()` is inappropriate when the variable is guaranteed to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if it is empty without white-spaces using this comparison:

```
if(!strlen(trim($text))){
  // To do: 
}
```

Reference: [PHP type comparison tables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)